# getContacts is not able to get information from web server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, typescript, express

I am a beginner in **Node JS**, **Express JS** and **Angular JS**, I am trying to develop a contact application, at server side programming I am using **Node JS** and **Express JS** which is working fine and **MONGO DB** I am using as my database, my server side programming is working fine with post man I have tested,

For development at client side programming I am using **Angular JS**, so what I did here, create new app "**Client**" then generate one more component **contacts**, and then generate service **contact**. and also "**import http from @angular/core**". so up to what ever I program in **contacts.component.html** and display it in **app.component.html** by selector **app-contact**, I am able to get this on my webpage and is working fine. but when I am trying to get contact information from web server its failed, I am not getting any specific error but on webpage nothing is appearing.

Specifically when I make constructor in my contacts component  and passing parameter private contact Service: Contact Service like this "constructor(/*private contact Service: Contact Service*/) { }" its even disappear all local information like "title"

/*private contactService: ContactService*/

==============================contact.ts===========================

```
    export class Contact{
    _id?: string;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    phone: string;}
```

============================contact.service.ts=====================

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Contact} from './contact';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable() 
 
export class ContactService {

  contacts: Contact[];

 constructor(private http: Http) { }

 getContacts()
 {
   return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/contacts").map(res => res.json());
 }
 
 addContact(newContact)
 {
   var headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
   return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/contact', newContact, { headers: headers })
     .map(res => res.json());
 }

 deleteContact(id)
 {
   return this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/contact/' + id)
     .map(res => res.json());
 }
}
```

==============================contacts.component.ts====================

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ContactService} from '../contact.service';
import { Contact } from '../contact';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-contacts',
 templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.css'],
 providers: [ContactService]
})
export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit {

 contacts: Contact[];
 contact: Contact;
 first_name: string;
 last_name: string;
 phone: string;

 constructor(private contactService: ContactService) { }


   ngOnInit() : void
   {
     
       this.contactService.getContacts()
         .subscribe(contacts =>
         this.contacts = contacts);   
     }
 }
```

======================contacts.component.html===================

```
    
<h2>contacts works!</h2>

<div class = "container">
    <div *ngFor = "let contact of contacts">
      <div class = "col-md-3">
        {{contact.first_name}}
      </div>
      <div class = "col-md-3">
          {{contact.last_name}}
      </div>
      <div class = "col-md-3">
          {{contact.phone}}
      </div>   
    </div>
  </div>
```

================================app.component.html==================

```
<app-contacts><app-contacts>
```

this is all my code.

Comment: plz provide some code example

Comment: @mxncson code is attached

Comment: Try to add the pipe opeartor this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/contacts").pipe(map(res => res.json()));

Comment: @MuhammadHassan Are you sure your dependency injection is good in your component and also in your service ? Also what does the subscribe method does on your getContacts ? Does it resolve your http promise ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming everything in the logic is correct since you mentioned there were no errors. In that case you may wrap around you `div` with the `ngFor` portion with something like:

```
*ngIf="contacts && contacts.length"
```

To make sure that it exists before render. Let me know if that works for you.